# yield* vs yield on ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I've been tinkering with the new harmony generators on latest Node.js and libraries that use them for flow-control like [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co), [gen-run](https://github.com/creationix/gen-run) or [gene](https://github.com/tasogarepg/gene)

The use of `yield` is quite clear but I've noticed the `yield*` syntax with nested generator functions in the later two libraries but not in the first. I can't find any reference about it. ¿What are the  differences and use cases?

Comment: See [Delegating Yield](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators#delegating_yield) in the Harmony wiki. That should explain it.

Comment: Good, so if I understood correctly in the case of [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co/blob/master/index.js) there is no need of use the yield* because of the `toThunk` function will call recursively `co` when you yield another generator function, right?